# ggplot2 - create one colorbar legend for two plots with different data-range

Tags: r, ggplot2, range, legend, colorbar

I have the following gridded [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6htk9vkw3su1eik/example.csv?dl=0) from where I create two different dataframes:

```
df_1=read.csv("example.csv")

df_2=df_1
df_2$var=df_2$var+50
```

Then I plot them with ggplot2 and metR:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)

plot_df_1=ggplot()+
  geom_contour_fill(data=df_1, aes(x=lon, y=lat, z=var), alpha=0.9) +
  scale_fill_steps(name = "", low = "#bdd7e7", high = "#08519c",
                   breaks = seq(0, 160, by = 10)) 

print(plot_df_1)
```

[image]

```
plot_df_2=ggplot()+
  geom_contour_fill(data=df_2, aes(x=lon, y=lat, z=var), alpha=0.9) +
  scale_fill_steps(name = "", low = "#bdd7e7", high = "#08519c",
                   breaks = seq(0, 160, by = 10)) 

print(plot_df_2)
```

[image]

Is there a way I can create one unique colorbar legend so that I can better compare the two plots?

The legend should have same colors and associated values for each plot.

In the two plots above the higest (lowest) values in both plots have the same color, but they differ in terms of magnitude. For example is it possible to show darker colors for plot_df_2 ?

Comment: You can row bind your data frames and create a new column (for ex.: Data_set) to identify the data set rows. 
Then use `facet_grid(~Data_set)` or `facet_wrap` to `ggplot` you data with the same legend and scale.

Comment: thanks, could you please provide a full answer if you have time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of implementing the solution described in @Mamoun Benghezai's comment:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(metR)

# Combine df1 and df2 to a single df ("df_table")
df_table <- map_df(.x = list("df_1" = df_1,
                             "df_2" = df_2),
                   .f = bind_rows,
                   .id = "src")

# Plot the combined dataset
plot_df_1 <- ggplot(df_table) +
  geom_contour_fill(aes(x=lon, y=lat, z=var), alpha=0.9) +
  scale_fill_steps(name = "", low = "#bdd7e7", high = "#08519c",
                   breaks = seq(0, 160, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(~src)

print(plot_df_1)
```